# In WinRT is there a way to ask for the hardware Make/Model?

Tags: windows-8

The subject has it all:

**In WinRT is there a way to ask for the hardware Make/Model?**

Let's say that for some reason Qualcom or Samsung hardware is important to you (like making an adjustment to an error in the compass driver). Is it possible to identify the Make/Model?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it out, but I would start looking here: [Windows.Devices.Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.aspx)

Specifically, the [DeviceInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.enumeration.deviceinformation.aspx) class seems useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use EasClientDeviceInformation, it contains all you need:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701390.aspx